# MySQL search in hebrew words without nekudot

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like, diacritics, hebrew

My MySQL DB work correctly with Hebrew text, just searching is strange.

```
SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE nekudot="כדי"
```

finds words with diacritics (nekudot): כְּדֵי
It is strange but it is what I want.

while

```
SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE nekudot like "%כדי%"
```

shows NOTHING! Not even previous result with nekudot: כְּדֵי

Please help me to write "like" clause to find כדי among  אכְּדֵימה.

Obviously it is really difficult... :-(

Comment: Does the column itself actually have Hebrew letters with vowel pointings?

Comment: You need to check the underlying byte values of the characters and what byte values the collation you use consider equivalent. It is possible that you need to use a different collation.

Comment: Yes, collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci should be ok. The column nekudot is full of words with nekudot. This select works a bit: select nekudot from dictionary where nekudot regexp '.*כ.*ד.*י.*'; to find word with כדי, but these letters can be distant a lot.